# How to use shortcutDetails (to get the id of the file the shortcut point at) in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy documents from a folder, and inside my folder I have some shortcuts. I want to copy the original file in my new folder so I'm trying to get the id of the real file using the id of the shortcut.

I tried to use `shortcutDetails` but I'm not sure how it works.

Here is my code:

```
function TestFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var id = "My shortcut Id";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  Logger.log(file.getMimeType());
  var a = file.shortcutDetails.targetId();
  Logger.log(a);
}
```

This is the result when I put my shortcut id:

[image]

Comment: Copy paste the text. Don't use images of code or error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var a = file.shortcutDetails.targetId();
```

#### To:

```
var a = file.getMimeType() == MimeType.SHORTCUT ? file.getTargetId() : id;
```

By this modification, when `file` is the shortcut file, the target file ID is returned. When `file` is not the shortcut file, `id` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [getTargetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#gettargetid)